# Creating a temporary variable in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I had a for loop designed to add 6 values to an arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = list.size(); i < list.size() + 6; i++){
    list.add(2 * i);
}
```

Now this produces an infinite loop. My question is whether or not I could declare a variable that persists throughout the whole `for` loop, that isn't `i` or would I have to declare it before the loop? If I can embed it in the `for` loop, where would I put it?

Comment: If you just want to add 6 things, why are you depending on the list's size?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

Comment: If the variable is also of type `int`, you could add it to the first part of the `for` statement, separated from `i` with a comma.

Comment: @Pavlo the code OP has shown, the control variable starts at `list.size()` not `0`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm using the size, as the way the problem I wrote it for was worded, the declaration and the loop adding the values may be at different spots, so I wrote a loop that will always add to the end, with two times the index.

Comment: additional variable should be before for statement. It will be accessible in loop body and after it

Comment: @PeregrineLennert `list.add(E e)` will **allways** add at the end of the list. Whatever you are trying to do is not necessary.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop. Once you add enough elements to the list, `list.size() + 6` will overflow. [Example](https://ideone.com/3EL8rt).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, I know that it always adds to the end of the list. I need the for loop to use the index for specifying each element to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to declare your limit variable within the `for` statement, you can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = list.size(), n = list.size()+6; i < n; ++i) {
    list.add(2 * i);
}
```

In this case, since you just created the list, `list.size()` starts at zero, so you could omit the extra variable and just write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    list.add(2 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as many variable as you want in the initialisation of your for loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = list.size(), len = list.size() + 6; i < len; i++){
    list.add(2 * i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your condition takes the current size of the list which changes each time you add something to it. That's why you end up in an infinite loop because the current size will always be six elements short to end the loop.

You need to keep the initial size of the list in a variable, you might declare it outside the loop or by

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int max = list.size(), int i = max; i < max + 6; i++){
    list.add(2 * i);
}
```